# Paste text in an input box in a webpage embeded by webview in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I would like to paste text with a shortcut (e.g., CMD+V) in an input box in a webpage embeded by webview in electron.
In development mode, pasting text works without any implementation about it. But after packaging the app with `electron-packager`, pasting is not working. I do not have a clue for this.

If you want to see the code, please look at this repository: https://github.com/junghyun87/dictionary-in-tray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the code from your repository, and ran into the same issue on macOS when using the packaged app.

In order to enable the keyboard shortcuts, including the ones for Cut, Copy, Paste, they still have to be defined inside menu items, even if the menubar is hidden, which is normally the case for a Tray application.

And it seems that, for some reason, the *packaged* application doesn't include the usual standard menu items and associated shortcuts.

I've been able to restore the desired behavior by adding a `createMenu()` function defining a basic menu in `main.js`:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  createTray();
  createWindow();
  createMenu();
});

const createMenu = () => {
  const { Menu } = require('electron');
  let menuTemplate =
  [
    {
      label: app.getName(),
      submenu: [
        {role: 'quit'}
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Edit',
      submenu: [
        {role: 'undo'},
        {role: 'redo'},
        {role: 'cut'},
        {role: 'copy'},
        {role: 'paste'},
        {role: 'selectall'}
      ]
    }
  ];
  Menu.setApplicationMenu (Menu.buildFromTemplate (menuTemplate));
};
```

HTH...